# Error while using mosql mongodb to postgres translator

Tags: ruby, mongodb, postgresql, database-replication

I am using [MOSQL](https://github.com/stripe/mosql) to create a live database replica of a mongodb database in postgres. I install all the requirements.

My mosql query i ran in terminal:

```
mosql -c coll.yaml --sql postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/test --mongo mongodb://localhost:27017/
```

My mongodb collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562dd2ef5bd6681ad0f63868"),
    "name" : "manish",
    "score" : 23,
    "class" : "Engg"
}
...
```

My coll.yaml:

```
Flipkart:
    temp:
        :columns:
            - name: TEXT
            - score: INTEGER
            - class: TEXT
        :meta:
            :table: temp
            :extra_props: true
```

Error

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (coll.yaml): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 2 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in`parse_stream'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in`load'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `block in load_file'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in`open'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in `load_file'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/cli.rb:140:in`load_collections'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/cli.rb:152:in `run'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mosql-0.4.3/lib/mosql/cli.rb:16:in`run'
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mosql-0.4.3/bin/mosql:5:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /usr/local/bin/mosql:23:in`load'
>       from /usr/local/bin/mosql:23:in `'

How to remove the error?